# Java project running on eclipse but giving error while using batch

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, runtime-error

I made a project for my uni. where I need to pass command line arguments. It is running perfectly fine on eclipse but when I run it using a batch file.

[image: Error while compiling]

my batch file looks like

```
set path = "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin";
javac FileHand.java
java FileHand DirectBuffer 1024 Sample.txt
pause
```

Comment: `set path = "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin";` is wrong, firstly because, if it were the correct syntax, it would overwrite everything in your current `%path%` variable, and secondly because the correct syntax is `Set "VariableName=Variable Value"`. Both sides of the `=` character are included, so your code is creating a variable named `path<space>` with a value of `<space>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin";`.

Comment: so what will be the right way to write it.

Comment: Read my previous comment.

Comment: so the correct way will be set "path=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin"; ? am I right

Comment: No you are not right, the semicolon should also be part of your value data. There must be thousands of examples of it throughout this site, even under both [[tag:java]], and [[tag:batch-file]], please use the search facility in future. I would assume that you're looking for either, `Set "PATH=%PATH%C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin;"`, or `Set "PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin;%PATH%"`. _In order for the former to work correctly you'd need to be certain that the existing `%PATH%` value data ended with a semicolon, (some people forget to include it when they modify its content)_

Answer (score 1):

Do not set %path% at all. If you want to 'hardcode' the full path to java, then do so; write `C:\program files\....\javac`, or `SET JAVA_LOC=...` and then `%JAVALOC%\javac`. But, this is clearly is not needed; you messed up your SET PATH statement and yet javac is being invoked, so, you should probably just remove the entire 'set path' line.

The problem is classpath. There is a file named DirectBuffer.class. It is somewhere - you said that 'it works in eclipse', which means eclipse can find this file, because you told it where it is. You need to tell javac where it is. You do this as follows:

`javac -cp LOC1;LOC2;LOC3 FileHandjava`

`java -cp .;LOC1;LOC2;LOC3 FileHand DirectBuffer 1024 Sample.txt`

where `LOC1` is a path. It can be a directory, or a jar file. Your question does not make this clear, but let's say `DirectBuffer' is in the` com.foo.pkg`package (so, you have`import com.foo.pkg.DirectBuffer;` in your source file), then:

either:

```
cd (whatever you put for LOC1)
cd com\foo\pkg
dir
```

should print, amongst other things, 'DirectBuffer.class', or, if LOC1 is a jar file:

```
jar tvf (the jar file listed in LOC1)
```

should print `com/foo/pkg/DirectBuffer.class`, amongst other things. You've already told eclipse this, so now find those places where you did that and tell javac about it.